# Open a document programmatically in a portable way

Tags: java, windows, linux, process

is the following command working under Unix&Linux?

```
ProcessBuilder prcbdoc = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/C","start", "Documentation.doc");       
            prcbdoc.directory(new File(currentDir+"/docs/"));
            prcbdoc.start();
```

I'm not sure because of the `"cmd" "/c"`

€:

What would be an Linux CentOS equivalent command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't work. From Java documentation:

> a *command*, a list of strings which signifies the external program file to be invoked and its arguments, if any. **Which string lists represent a valid operating system command is system-dependent**. For example, it is common for each conceptual argument to be an element in this list, but there are operating systems where programs are expected to tokenize command line strings themselves - on such a system a Java implementation might require commands to contain exactly two elements.

To open a document in a portable manner using [AWT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html):

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
 Desktop.getDesktop().open(documentPath);
```

Comment: Thanks also for the Dekstop.open()

Comment: This does not work to open folders on my computer (Debian Linux/KDE). It should open Dolphin file manager, but it throws an IOException. Works for documents though.

Comment: Does it work if you manually run `xdg-open` from terminal? If a  _file manager_ is correctly configured then it should open it

Answer (score 1):

No, this would not work on Linux (or any other Unix, or on the Mac) due to the "cmd /c" and the "start". On the Mac, you'd say `"open Documentation.doc"`.The various Linux desktops have their own versions of the start/open command: `gnome-open` for the Gnome desktop, and the FreeDesktop semi-standard `xdg-open` are some possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

No. `cmd` and `/c` are relevant only for windows.